# js проверка на куки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хотел проверить с помощью js наличие куки на страничке. при правильном вводе данных в логине и пароле - куки создаются без проблем, **но скрипт js не работает**, не показывает ни текста при true ни при false. Я как-то проверяю не так? (Хочу именно через js проверить наличие определенных cookies)

index.php:

```
<script>
function functionBefore() {
    $(".information").text("Ожидание данных...");
}
function functionSuccess() {
    $(".information").text("Выполнено!");
}
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('.button').bind('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'processing.php',
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: functionBefore,
            success: functionSuccess
        });
    })
});
</script>
<form method="POST" action="php.php">
    <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="login">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<div class="information"></div>
```

processing.php:

```
<?
if ($_POST['login'] == 1 && $_POST['password'] == 1) {
setcookie('login','1', time()+3600);
} else {
return false;
}
```

**index.js**:

```
var myCookie = getCookie("login");
if (myCookie == null) {
    $(".information").text("Куки нет:(");
}
else {
    $(".information").text("Куки есть!!!");
}
```

> Прошу строго не судить, я не старичок в этом всем

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795269/get-on-the-client-cookies-set-by-the-server

Comment: что это за функция `getCookie` ?

Answer (score 0):

[Нашел код](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/blob/latest/src/js.cookie.js), с помощью которого можно легко в js узнавать, установлены ли cookies или нет. Мне следовало просто подключить его как отдельный файл для удобства и это упрощает всю задачу. В условии обращаться через Cookies.get('cookiename');

```
 /*!
 * JavaScript Cookie v2.2.0
 * https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie
 *
 * Copyright 2006, 2015 Klaus Hartl & Fagner Brack
 * Released under the MIT license
 */
;(function (factory) {
var registeredInModuleLoader = false;
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(factory);
    registeredInModuleLoader = true;
}
if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = factory();
    registeredInModuleLoader = true;
}
if (!registeredInModuleLoader) {
    var OldCookies = window.Cookies;
    var api = window.Cookies = factory();
    api.noConflict = function () {
        window.Cookies = OldCookies;
        return api;
    };
}
}(function () {
function extend () {
    var i = 0;
    var result = {};
    for (; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var attributes = arguments[ i ];
        for (var key in attributes) {
            result[key] = attributes[key];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function init (converter) {
    function api (key, value, attributes) {
        var result;
        if (typeof document === 'undefined') {
            return;
        }

        // Write

        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            attributes = extend({
                path: '/'
            }, api.defaults, attributes);

            if (typeof attributes.expires === 'number') {
                var expires = new Date();
                expires.setMilliseconds(expires.getMilliseconds() + attributes.expires * 864e+5);
                attributes.expires = expires;
            }

            // We're using "expires" because "max-age" is not supported by IE
            attributes.expires = attributes.expires ? attributes.expires.toUTCString() : '';

            try {
                result = JSON.stringify(value);
                if (/^[\{\[]/.test(result)) {
                    value = result;
                }
            } catch (e) {}

            if (!converter.write) {
                value = encodeURIComponent(String(value))
                    .replace(/%(23|24|26|2B|3A|3C|3E|3D|2F|3F|40|5B|5D|5E|60|7B|7D|7C)/g, decodeURIComponent);
            } else {
                value = converter.write(value, key);
            }

            key = encodeURIComponent(String(key));
            key = key.replace(/%(23|24|26|2B|5E|60|7C)/g, decodeURIComponent);
            key = key.replace(/[\(\)]/g, escape);

            var stringifiedAttributes = '';

            for (var attributeName in attributes) {
                if (!attributes[attributeName]) {
                    continue;
                }
                stringifiedAttributes += '; ' + attributeName;
                if (attributes[attributeName] === true) {
                    continue;
                }
                stringifiedAttributes += '=' + attributes[attributeName];
            }
            return (document.cookie = key + '=' + value + stringifiedAttributes);
        }

        // Read

        if (!key) {
            result = {};
        }

        // To prevent the for loop in the first place assign an empty array
        // in case there are no cookies at all. Also prevents odd result when
        // calling "get()"
        var cookies = document.cookie ? document.cookie.split('; ') : [];
        var rdecode = /(%[0-9A-Z]{2})+/g;
        var i = 0;

        for (; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var parts = cookies[i].split('=');
            var cookie = parts.slice(1).join('=');

            if (!this.json && cookie.charAt(0) === '"') {
                cookie = cookie.slice(1, -1);
            }

            try {
                var name = parts[0].replace(rdecode, decodeURIComponent);
                cookie = converter.read ?
                    converter.read(cookie, name) : converter(cookie, name) ||
                    cookie.replace(rdecode, decodeURIComponent);

                if (this.json) {
                    try {
                        cookie = JSON.parse(cookie);
                    } catch (e) {}
                }

                if (key === name) {
                    result = cookie;
                    break;
                }

                if (!key) {
                    result[name] = cookie;
                }
            } catch (e) {}
        }

        return result;
    }

    api.set = api;
    api.get = function (key) {
        return api.call(api, key);
    };
    api.getJSON = function () {
        return api.apply({
            json: true
        }, [].slice.call(arguments));
    };
    api.defaults = {};

    api.remove = function (key, attributes) {
        api(key, '', extend(attributes, {
            expires: -1
        }));
    };

    api.withConverter = init;

    return api;
}

return init(function () {});
}));
```